# Can I delete tabs from the server template using composite templates?

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Is it possible to delete some tabs from the server templates when using composite templates while creating the envelope rather than having to send another HTTP delete request to delete template tabs not required?

Answer (score 1):

you can delete tabs from the template, or from an envelope
2 different API points
if you do it on the envelope, it's for that one transaction.
if you do it on the template - it will be for any future envelope created from that template.
Hope this helps.